# Java jump to section in MS Word document

Tags: java, com, ms-word

I'm trying to open and jump to a particular section in a Word document from Java. I don't need Java to read the document, but really just open MS word. I know I could launch it using a Runtime exec but I couldn't jump to a specific section that way (I don't think - unless there is a command line arg for that for in Word but I didn't see one). I was looking into using the JACOB Java COM bridge but I've found little documentation on how to manipulate MS Word.

Anything to point in the right direction here would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33305 is an article on opening up Word using Jacob.  I've done similiar in the past - but never really tried to navigate in the document - just open it and save in a different format.